# How to set values to object attributes inside an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, setter

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Circle.main(Circle.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I'm trying to set the attributes for the first circle object, but I guess I can't do this in java this way?

```
public class Circle {
    private double x,
                   y,
                   radius;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Testing Circles
        System.out.println("\nTESTING CIRCLES:");
        Circle[] circles = new Circle[2];
        Circle circle1 = circles[0]; // Circle 1

        // Setting X
        circle1.setX(20);  // <- Why does this not work and how is this properly done.
    }

    public void setX(double xVal) {
        x = xVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not initialized your `Circle` object, just declared an empty array that is fit to hold circle objects. At the time of declaration, all objects in the array are `null`. You need to initialize the objects in the array before you're able to call methods on them.

```
Circle[] circles = new Circle[2];
circles[0] = new Circle();
circles[0].setX(20);
```

Or you can do initialization and declaration in one line as follows:

```
Circle[] circles = new Circle[] { new Circle(), new Circle() };
circles[0].setX(20);
```

Comment: The latter is wrong because you can't have both a dimension expression and an array initializer. It should be `Circle[] circles = new Circle[] { new Circle(), new Circle() };`, or better, `Circle[] circles = { new Circle(), new Circle() };`

Comment: @johnchen902 My bad. Correcting my answer.